# Need help in configuring Hadoop 0.23.8

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to configure hadoop-0.23.8 on my local computer. And I am running in with the following exception. Do you guys know what I am doing wrong

I am using the following system var

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm=OX.AC.UK -Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc0.ox.ac.uk:kdc1.ox.ac.uk"
```

Also I am using java 6 and have set the following variables HADOOP_PREFIX, HADOOP_HDFS_HOME and YARN_HOME. Could you help in configuring it correctly.

```
192.168.1.13: namenode running as process 10522. Stop it first.
hduser@192.168.1.13: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.23.8/logs/hadoop-
hduser-datanode-MacBook-Air.local.out
hduser@192.168.1.13: 2013-06-19 00:30:30.556 java[11171:1603] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
hduser@192.168.1.13: 2013-06-19 00:30:30.558 java[11171:1603] Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
Starting secondary namenodes []
hduser@192.168.1.13: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-0.23.8/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-MacBook-Air.local.out
hduser@192.168.1.13: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target address cannot be null.
hduser@192.168.1.13:    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:179)
hduser@192.168.1.13:    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:154)
hduser@192.168.1.13:    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:143)
hduser@192.168.1.13:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil.getNameServiceId(DFSUtil.java:771)
hduser@192.168.1.13:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil.getSecondaryNameServiceId(DFSUtil.java:738)
hduser@192.168.1.13:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.<init>(SecondaryNameNode.java:186)
hduser@192.168.1.13:    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:691)
```

Comment: First make sure that no other daemon is running when you are starting. The first line of log is saying that name node is already running. Try stopping it or killing it mannually

Comment: I restarted my computer and killed all the daemons, and am still getting the same error.

Comment: did you check your ps -ef | grep "namenode" . As per the logs the namenode is running and the process id is also given. Try killing  this process specifically

Comment: I restarted my computer after killing all the daemons, I dont think it is possible for the namenode to still be running, but I shall do what you suggested.

Comment: my initial debugging instinct says this "namenode running as process 10522. Stop it first." message should go . Thats why suggesting you

Comment: So no namenodes to kill and still getting the above error, do you know if there is any documentation for configuring hadoop-0.23.8 as I cannot find any online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there was a small Typo in one of my config files, sorry about this, but I found some important info for configuring hadoop 0.23.8. in the etc/hadoop folder make a file called hadoop-env.sh in which we put JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_OPTS. etc